# How to process data from multiple checkboxes sharing the same value?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

So I have a code that is supposed to show the data from a mysql table and each row have a checkbox included at the end of it which's purpose is to transfer the entire row into a different table after submission if checked. The code is working fine but no matter how many rows you have selected it always moves only one row and my question here is how can i code it further so it can transfer all of the selected rows with one hit

After lots of research i somehow concluded that i should be using a foreach loop (which i am not familiar with) and when i replace my $rowid with this

```
foreach ($_POST['checks'] as $check){
        $rowid = $check;
    }
```

$rowid looses it's original value and the entire function stops working

Here goes my working code that moves only one row:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'orders');

$query = "SELECT * FROM received ORDER BY date";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Contact Info</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Order Type</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Date Ordered</th>
    <th>Complete Order</th>
</tr>
<form action='#' method='POST'>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'
        <br />
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["clientname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["contactinfo"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["ordertype"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["amount"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" value='.$row["id"].' /></td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
?>
</table>
<button name="complete" class="regbutton">Complete Orders</button>
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['complete'])){
    $rowid = $_POST['checks'];
        if(isset($_POST['checks'])){
            $query = "INSERT INTO delivered SELECT * FROM received WHERE id = '$rowid'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            $query = "DELETE FROM received WHERE id = '$rowid'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            echo "<script>alert('Eureka!');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script>alert('Nothing is checked!');</script>"; 
        }
}
?>
```

I expected the $check variable to show the exact id/s of the selected row/s and hopefully move each row selected but it is not doing it

I have also tried to put the entire if(isset($_POST['checks.. statement inside the loop ..WHERE id = '$check.. but it is not working either way

Comment: name="checks" should be name="checks[]" then $_POST['checks'] will be an array, you will then need to loop through them to insert delivered status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the checkbox's name so it can become an array like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value='.$row["id"].' />
```

then add the statement to be executed inside the loop, also change the WHERE condition's variable representing the selected checkbox/s value (from $rowid to $check)

```
foreach ($_POST['checks'] as $check){

        if(isset($_POST['checks'])){
            $query = "INSERT INTO delivered SELECT * FROM received WHERE id = '$check'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            $query = "DELETE FROM received WHERE id = '$check'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            echo "<script>alert('Eureka!');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script>alert('Nothing is checked!');</script>"; 
        }
    }
```

**answer taken from question's comments**